# /usr/lib/ Symbolic Link Gets Over Written during boot

Tags: boot, xinerama

To get the tri-monitor setup I want, I am using the libXinerama hack that allows me fake my layout.

In order to use this, I use a patched version of libXinerama and put it in `/usr/lib` and then change the libXinerama.so symbolic link to point to it:

```
[kbrandt@alpine: /usr/lib] ls -l libXinerama.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7286 2010-05-18 07:57 libXinerama.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20 2011-02-27 19:59 libXinerama.so -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20 2011-05-06 11:31 libXinerama.so.1 -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8659 2011-04-11 09:40 libXinerama.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10432 2011-02-27 20:01 libXinerama.so.1.0.0.back
```

This work fine, except on reboot it rewrites the link and points it to libXinerama.so.1.0.0.back which breaks my setup. What process is doing this, and how can I stop it from doing it?

Comment: I think you can change the attribute of the symbolic link so it won't be overwrited. ' sudo chattr +i'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `ldconfig` is being called somewhere, and `libXinerama.so.1.0.0.back` sorts after `libXinerama.so.1.0.0` so it is being selected as the newest version of the library.

Why exactly do you need to patch the Xinerama extension's client library in the first place?

Comment: K, I have just removed the back version from the folder, seems to have stopped happening. As to why, 3 headed display kind of sucks unless I have two as TwinView and then a standalone X session for the third. Since my monitors are not the same size for the TwinView, I need to fake it: http://superuser.com/questions/115076/how-to-vertically-split-widescreen-into-two-virtual-workspaces-on-ubuntu-gnome/115215#115215